# Unable to setup Google Cloud Memorystore redis instance with Serverless VPC access

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-memorystore

I'm wanting to setup a Google Cloud memorystore redis instance and connect to it through my google cloud functions. After following this guide https://thecloudfunction.com/blog/firebase-cloud-functions-and-redis/

The general steps as I understand are:

1. Enable Serverless VPC Service and create a connector for my function to use.
2. Enable redis and create a redis instance on the same IP address range.

The problem is if I create the connector first (step #1) then I get this error when trying to create a redis instance (step #2):

```
Server response: Invalid value for field 'resource.ipCidrRange': '10.92.0.0/28'. Invalid IPCidrRange: 10.92.0.0/28 conflicts with peer network in active peering 'redis-peer-863826821838'.
```

And if I try and flip the steps, create the redis instance first (step #2) and then create the connector (step #1) then I get this error when trying to create the connector:

```
connector is in a bad state manual deletion recommended
```

I assume this is a problem with some IP range conflict per the first error but looking at the VPC connections I don't see a conflict anywhere:

[image]

As far as I understand none of these should conflict with my IP range of `10.92.0.0/28`, right?

All of this is happening on `us-central1`

Wondering if anyone knows how to correctly setup a redis instance + connector and move past these errors or if anyone has any suggestions on where to look for this IP range conflict and how to solve for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so finally got this to work. For anyone else struggling with this issue here is what I had to do:

1. Create a redis instance, and instead of manually entering `Instance IP address range`. Skip the field and create it without one. This is will generate a redis instance that doesn't conflict with any other ranged. For example `10.51.123.233`
2. Now create the connector and set it to the ip range of the created redis instance. For example if your redis instance generated an IP of `10.51.123.233` then you need to set the connect IP range to `10.51.0.0/28`

Comment: This worked because the IP range for the connector 10.51.0.0/28 does 'not' include 10.51.123.233. I was making the same mistake thinking I was connecting the function to redis when in fact I was designating the IP for the connector & redis to 'occupy'.

Answer (score 0):

### IP Address will be 'occupied' by the service

I was learning GCP functions & redis using [the official guide](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-functions). In summary...

Is good to learn a bit about CIDR. I found this [online tool](https://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr) helpful.

- Essentially the /28 indicates how many of the 32-bits are 'locked' as the prefix. 28 leaves 4 wildcard bits which is 16 addresses

Redis and connector **addresses must not overlap**. Like OP, I thought I was connecting the redis IP to the function but this is wrong. The IP address inside your VPC will be 'occupied' by the connector. Same for redis.

I successfully created a connector instance by designating a custom subnet (created in advance with CIDR 10.1.0.0/28)

```
gcloud compute networks vpc-access connectors create connector6 \
--region=us-central1 \
--subnet=connector-subnet \
--machine-type f1-micro
```

However, creating a subnet for the redis instance did not work. Instead, a 'redis-peer-...' VPC network peer was created and caused the ip conflict message in OP above.

```
# BAD: Creating subnet 'redis-subnet' with CIDR 10.2.0.0/28
gcloud redis instances create redis6 \
--region=us-central1 --redis-version=redis_5_0 \
--network=vpc1 --reserved-ip-range=10.2.0.0/28
```

Designating a fresh IP range worked.

```
gcloud redis instances create redis6 \
--region=us-central1 --redis-version=redis_5_0 \
--network=vpc1 --reserved-ip-range=10.3.0.0/28
```

Finally, deploying the function again worked.

```
gcloud functions deploy visitCount \
--runtime nodejs10 \
--trigger-http \
--region us-central1 \
--vpc-connector projects/fc-redis-tutorial/locations/us-central1/connectors/connector6 \
--set-env-vars REDISHOST=10.3.0.3,REDISPORT=6379
```